# For in assembly, "syntax error" without errors

Tags: assembly, tasm

I'm trying to do a for loop in assembly. I'm using TASM and TLINK.  I also have a library that my professor gave to me, but I'm trying to do all the things on my own, and to my surprise, it's not working. So, I just copy pasted my profesor's code and I receive the same error. The error is as follows.

I can compile with TASM, even i create the .exe, I run it, and after running it, insted of doing what it supposed to do, it just says "Syntax error".

Here's my code:

```
MODEL small
.stack 100h
    N   equ 20
.DATA
    mensaje     db "Hola mundo",10,13,"$"
    mensajefin  db  "Finalizo el for, presiona cualquier tecla para terminar$"
    i           db  (?)
.code
imprimefor  PROC
            mov ax,@data
            mov ds,ax
            mov ah,03h
            int 10h
            mov [i],0
@@for_cmp:  cmp [i],N
            ja @@for_end
            mov dx,offset mensaje
            mov ah,09h
            int 21h
            inc [i]
            jmp @@for_cmp
@@for_end:  mov dx,offset mensajefin
            mov ah,09h
            int 21h
            mov ah,01h
            int 21h
            mov ax,4c00h
            int 21
            ENDP
    END
```

Here's my professor's:

```
MODEL small
   .STACK 100h

   ;----- Insert INCLUDE "filename" directives here
   ;----- Insert EQU and = equates here
 INCLUDE procs.inc

       LOCALS

      N     equ 20
      CR    EQU 13
      LF    EQU 10

   .DATA
      mens       db  'Hola Mundo',CR,LF,0
        i        db (?)


   .CODE
    ;-----   Insert program, subrutine call, etc., here

    Principal   PROC
                mov ax,@data    
                mov ds,ax       

                call clrscr

                ; i=0
                mov [i],0

                ; i<n
     @@cmp_for: cmp [i],N
                ja @@fin_for

                mov al,[i]
                inc al
                add al,30h    ; convierte a ASCII

                call putchar

                mov ax,'-'
                call putchar                

                mov  dx,offset mens
                call puts

                ; i++
                inc [i]
                jmp @@cmp_for

     @@fin_for: call getch

                mov ah,04ch      ; fin de programa
                mov al,0             ;
                int 21h              ; 

                ENDP
         END
```

I looked in a lot of places but I haven't been able to find anything that helps. Any suggestions? Also my professor has a broken leg, so he's not teaching classes to us, so we're kinda screwed.

Comment: What have you called this executable program?

Comment: for.exe, haha also i noticed that i didn't translate to english some of the code, haha sorry! Hola mundo means hello world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't call your executable `for.exe`, that's just asking for trouble.

`FOR` is actually a DOS/Windows internal command so, if you type in `for` at the command prompt, it will complain bitterly:

```
c:\Users\Pax> for
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

You can get around this by using a full path specification, as you can see in the following transcript:

```
c:\Users\Pax> type for.cmd
@echo off
echo hello

c:\Users\Pax> for
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

c:\Users\Pax> .\for
hello
```

You can see that, although `cmd.exe` treats `for` as the internal command, the *filespec* `.\for` is treated as an external executable (a batch file in this case, but an `exe` file in yours).

Comment: OHHHHH MEN! hahahahaha you got it, now it's working. Dude, thanks! Haha such a little thing can cause such problems. Thanks again.

Comment: @Hector, that's nothing, I once shortened a constants header file from `const.h` to `con.h` and wondered why the compiler started hanging. Turns out MSDOS treated `con` with _any_ extension as the console device `con:` meaning it was waiting for me to actually _type in_ a header :-) Ah, the things that bite us in our long careers.

Comment: Haha ohh yes, sometimes i think that we engineers have certain love for pain... haha. Man, i owe you.

Answer (score 0):

For instructions for to write an immediate value to a memory location we need to specify how many bytes we want to access, only one byte, a word, or a dword.

```
mov byte ptr [i],0 ; MASM
mov byte [i],0    ; NASM
```

Dirk